# GAN losses balance, but quality of generated image still bad

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-models, gan

I build a GAN to train on the fashion mnist dataset. [image]

To facilitate the training, I have added gaussian noise with mean 0 and stddev 0.15 on the images. My generator is a 2 layer MLP with sigmoid activation, discriminator is a logistic regression

I trained this for 100k rounds and the loss started to stablize at around 20000.
[image]

So I thought this is good, since the loss of the generator and discriminator are not too far apart. But looking at the generated images, it's another story[image]

I wonder why? Similar situation has happened before when I built a variational autoencoder.

Comment: The original GANs are notoriously unstable to train. Have you tried instead doing e.g. a WGAN-GP?

Comment: @Dougal No i haven't but thanks for pointing that out. I realized my generator might be too small, so i am trying to increase the depth and see what happens

Comment: +1 on too small generator : try DCGAN