# Trying to understand CGAN loss curves

Tags: python, gan

I am trying to understand the loss curves of a CGAN model better. From what I've seen so far, it seems like there is no consistent answer as to what the loss curves should look like. Some tutorials such as [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) shows both the generator and discriminator losses decrease with a bigger reduction in the generator loss.

However, some other papers and tutorials such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330834/gan-losses-balance-but-quality-of-generated-image-still-bad), shows the two losses converges to a certain point, which is what I was expecting.

It seems like it could be due to the GAN structure, for example, in this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-generator-loss-discriminator-loss-and-average-loss-changes-during-the-training_fig3_339417739), in Figure 3, it showed the loss curves for CGAN, WCGAN, and improved CGAN and they all behave differently.

Is this the right takeaway? I am fairly new to the world of GAN and trying to understand what to expect from the loss curves has been quite difficult for me. So any suggestions or comments would be much appreciated!